# SharePoint 2010 Ocassionally not saving user's changes

Tags: document-library, check-in

Our users are experiencing an elusive issue in which their changes will not save to sharepoint. I have watched the users procedure for editing the documents, and this issue is occuring randomly throughout the organization on different machines/users.

A little background info:
-Sharepoint 2010
-Users are mixed using Office2003/Office 2010- both experiencing the issue
-Versioning enabled within the library
-Checkout is required to edit

What is being reported is that a user will check a file out to be edited, make changes, hit save- and their changes will not reflect on sharepoint. Another strange thing is that the user who had previously checked the document out to be edited no longer has the ability to check the document back in- though it is still being reported as checked out by that user on the sharepoint web interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply- I advised my users to do this. One user is no longer experiencing the issue while another (remote) user still is experiencing the issue. I cannot say for sure if this helped with the issue. I will advise as I learn more info.

Answer (score 2):

We had an almost identical problem with the documents and the solution was to have the user clear out their IE cache Under Internet Options -> Browsing History. (I had them clear everything.) Then the user had to start Disk Cleanup and checked off Temporary Internet Files and deleted them as well. This cleared up the save issue and locking as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: The above answer - Clearing out IE cache and then deleting temporary files with Disk Cleanup - worked perfectly for my users who were having an identical problem as the one described.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, and will not get an answer flag, but maybe it will help a fellow administrator.

I just had the same issue and discovered that it worked fine with IE (32 bit) but experienced the above anomaly with IE (64 bit).  Swapped out the shortcuts on the user's desktop.